# TypeScript generics: union of generic properties

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typechecking

I have a notion of a step. It takes an input and produces an output.

This is a simplified example to demonstrate the problem (so it might be lacking some extra beef with correct type restrictions, etc). We are interested in the `andThen` function which accumulates state as it goes through steps. No questions to this block of code, it is just for reference.

```
type SubType<T, U> = T extends U ? U : never;

class Step<A, B> {
  constructor(private readonly f: (a: A) => B) { }

  public run(a: A): B {
    return this.f(a);
  }

  public andThen<C, D>(nextStep: Step<SubType<B, C> | B, D>): Step<A, B & D> {
    return new Step<A, B & D>((state: A) => {
      const b = this.f(state);
      return { ...b, ...nextStep.run(b) };
    });
  }
}
```

The following works just fine, we have two steps, types are inferred automatically and we end up with `all` having expected type `{ user1: User, user2: User }`

```
type User = { id: number, name: string };

const user1 = new Step((input: {}) => ({ user1: { id: 1, name: "A" } }));
const user2 = new Step((input: {}) => ({ user2: { id: 2, name: "B" } }));

const all = user1.andThen(user2).run({})
```

My next step was to reuse the same abstraction when dealing with the same function which produces result, but the only difference I would like to have is the key under which the result goes. You probably didn't understand what I just said, so let me show you the code:

```
class UserStep<K extends string> extends Step<{}, { [k in K]: User }> { }

const user21 = new UserStep<"user1">((input: {}) => ({ user1: { id: 1, name: "A" } }));
const user22 = new UserStep<"user2">((input: {}) => ({ user2: { id: 2, name: "B" } }));

// inferred type here is wrong { user1: User } instead of { user1: User, user2: User }
const all2 = user21.andThen(user22).run({})
```

`UserStep` should handle creation of the user (or whatever other job it needs to do) and I would like it to return the result in an object with key `K extends string`. Once again everything type checks automatically and seems to be working BUT there is a problem with `all2` where the type is inferred *incorrectly* (most likely it is correct, but it is different from expected). I understand that it is most likely has to do something with how the `UserStep` is defined and its key is `K extends string` but I fail to see what other approach I could have taken to make this `UserStep` work as expected.

So the question is:
is there a way to abstract `UserStep` so that it returns whatever the result it wants with different keys, so that after composing steps using `andThen` type checker infers correct/expected type?

Comment: Ugh, something is screwy with the way TypeScript is checking the variance on the `A` type parameter; it should be contravariant in `A` but the compiler doesn't see it ([minimal example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIgDwEEA0yBCAfMgN4CwAUMtcgBRwBcyWAlE-gNyU3IAmA9iAhNaMECIBG7FsgC8xAG79gvGfLSZcyJSsJcKAX0qVeEBABs4UFAkEBnMMhhN0GB1FABzPCACuAWwloPUpbEAdkTxdMACI4GJ8AoKhiWScOZAB6TORoKH4oAEIAfkps5AAVAE8ABxQAcld3L0TA4PrkYDtkEH5HODs7YE8QOAlzFDB+ZDBahtc4hJ6k9oA6MpzquuR65pBPDq6evuQBoZGxiZnp2e36xfrV2gAmAGZn55kN5FXf5AlfI4AO4ACyqnW6ri0RGOjjCYCgcAUVmAcHAnRAzFKFCAA))

Comment: Your `SubType` and added `C` type parameter seem to be workarounds for this, but it has unfortunate implications about type inference.  Does the following workaround suffice instead?

Comment: [Playgrnd Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuBTADgHgIIBpoCEB80A3gLABQ0F0wA9gHYTwBOArsPNYwBTLMBGIAS2DQAZgC5onMBPQBKaAF4COeYWgBfMpWg9+Q6C1pSZsiTiJbtlRonjNGtaPAAWAiADoRU2QG5LFTXJKXUFhMFoAEwAVZ0RaVABhbAARPE5aRAAPeAQUCVy0BOgAH1wUvFM4JDQsXGgAMmhUiyCrA1t7R1pmEBAAQmgAekHoAQBbZBBoajGBeCQI0Q5oXhsANzmAT38NMkD4TeREaABVCERGRSJRiIlusd4L7FowMcQJBkYBWgBzDT9SKBIDAzhcCqgANLQLJISIwT7fH4EGFxCIwcGEdTYNQAbQA1qNHBCALoSUGXdQENSBEC2aDMACMVwyAHdTudGOCAETMDkMrlpTjfHjwCSY+RKSRqXkXBlim4SBnPV7vaBc9BcjQaWS+Mi0+D0gBMzMQbPJ3JljENAs4QtoIrF6glBE40o5hvlAlu0ENyreEi5OE16m1utI+ugYF6V0Z7nC0ViRmYhtk7kMrqdQA)

Comment: @jcalz hm, wow, your workaround seems to be doing everything i want it to do (haven't found any issues in a small time span i have allocated to it). Do you maybe want to add an answer so i could credit you with an acceptable solution?

Comment: I think it might accept weird things from `andThen()` though.  I'm still researching the issue and will add an answer when I get enough info

Comment: In case it matters I've filed [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35805) to ask about the underlying variance problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: the error below has been [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36261) in the latest build of TypeScript and is likely to be released with TS3.8.  At that point you should be able to just use the "most reasonable typing" of `Step<A, B>` below, without union or `SubType` workarounds, and everything should  just work.

---

The underlying issue here is that the type checker doesn't realize that the most reasonable typing of `Step<A, B>`, namely:

```
interface Step<A, B> {
    f: (a: A) => B;
    andThen<C>(next: Step<B, C>): Step<A, B & C>;
}
```

is [*contravariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in `A`.  Meaning that `Step<T, B>` is assignable to `Step<U, B>` if and only if `U` is assignable to `T`.  The switch in assignability direction is the "contra" part.  Had it been the same direction, as in "`F<T>` is assignable to `F<U>` if and only if `T` is assignable to `U`", it would be *covariant*.

Anyway, that means you get an error here:

```
declare const u1: Step<{}, { user1: {} }>;
declare const u2: Step<{}, { user2: {} }>;
let u1u2 = u1.andThen(u2); // error!?
// Type 'Step<{}, any>' is not assignable to type 'Step<{ user1: {}; }, any>'.
// Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ user1: {}; }'.
```

The reason it doesn't realize that `Step<A, B>` is contravariant in `A` is because `Step<A, B>`'s `andThen()` method involves `Step` itself, and when checking variance for type parameters in such recursive generic types, the type checker assumes it to be covariant, as mentioned in a comment inside the `typeArgumentsRelatedTo()` function in [`checker.ts`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/v3.7.3/src/compiler/checker.ts):

> `// When variance information isn't available we default to covariance`

(Thanks to [jack-williams](https://github.com/jack-williams) for his [helpful comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32674#issuecomment-567621941) about this)

This is either a bug or a design limitation; ideally the compiler would not make any default guess and instead check for structural compatibility.  I don't think there are any existing GitHub issues surrounding this particular problem, so I have filed [microsoft/TypeScript#35805](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35805) to ask about it.  The general lack of ability for developers to add variance hints is covered in [microsoft/TypeScript#1394](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1394).

---

Anyway, to deal with this it looks like you used a workaround to make the `andThen()` method not trip up the variance checker while still relating `A` contravariantly:

```
    type SubType<T, U> = T extends U ? U : never;
    interface Step<A, B> {
        f: (a: A) => B;
        andThen<C, X>(next: Step<B | SubType<B, X>, C>): Step<A, B & C>;
    }
    declare const u1: Step<{}, { user1: {} }>;
    declare const u2: Step<{}, { user2: {} }>;
    let u1u2 = u1.andThen(u2); // okay
```

Unfortunately, as you've seen, type inference in the face of generic conditional types like `SubType` can be messy:

```
    type User = { id: number, name: string };
    interface UserStep<K extends string> extends Step<{}, { [k in K]: User }> { }
    declare const v1: UserStep<"user1">;
    declare const v2: UserStep<"user2">;
    let v1v2 = v1.andThen(v2); // Step<{}, {user1: User;}> !!
```

The easiest "fix" to this is just to manually specify the type parameters it doesn't infer properly:

```
    let v1v2Fixed = v1.andThen<{ user2: User }, {}>(v2); // okay:
    // Step<{}, { user1: User;} & { user2: User;}>
```

---

A different workaround which I *think* has the same behavior around contravariance is this:

```
    interface Step<A, B> {
        f: (a: A) => B;
        andThen<C, X>(next: Step<B | X, C>): Step<A, B & C>;
    }
```

But here there are no generic conditional types to worry about, and the compiler is much better at inferring things:

```
    let v1v2 = v1.andThen(v2); // okay:
    // Step<{}, { user1: User;} & { user2: User;}>
```

So that might be my suggestion.  You should really test it, though, since there are often crazy edge cases.  Hopefully eventually the variance thing will just be fixed "the right way", but for now at least you have some options.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBIlKiSwLICSAJhJnkaS0gJbAAuEATgGZUkAZW4wAPAEEANEgBCAPibFWKvgC4kAChAaJASiQBeRbIDczFaxDBaAFQAWEYGIDC8zcAgAPThpERxWRk3PT9RSRlZJAAyJDdzZRUAXwsVengMEB5keAB7YChOJABXAEYwgLFcJJlcEqhecrwkpCT5BMskdMzspDyCouKAJgrxatr63hHm1vbU1gwIQdLhoxLSgDprO0dgTWG9UyQAemOkXh5cngBCAH55llOkWwBPGGQAcn8xmqRrF-kH3YUDIuSKICgUDYAHNQAAjRZITi5JFvT7fKqTHhNapHX7-QEbB6kJ6vd5ID7VIFsEHAMF-SEw+GI5Go8mUrE4pJ4j5EwjzFL8xJkcDQOCIJAAdSuAGssrlijYlJ1OGjhMU4WSIGJbDIAKqKQzPc4+Jy0EF6pC3JCWjSeABuvA6lg43H4ggx0jkigIws66i0OiQ+iMJmdnRI2wcTlcMgAGu5PD5RmIogAfdWatGp+PyYLyULCcJeqKxeLEkiCzrdLI5fKFdYp8Z4TkaaqzcOsGu9foN4ZN351YoNHjTdttI4VpCLZarI1lLY2aN7A5HJ65OUvIhT1XkvUjtZ1Ni0O3FMBw3gycgQDSFHgcaGtTssV28AQS-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)

Comment: @ksaveljev you might want to check out the newest builds of TS (3.8.0-dev.20200118 and up), since the contravariance issue I filed has been fixed.  This should let you use `interface Step<A, B> {  f: (a: A) => B; run(a: A): B; andThen<C>(next: Step<B, C>): Step<A, B & C>; }` directly without `SubType` or unions.